# Spring Controller doesn't load the correct view

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I am working on spring. I have the controller `AdminProduitsController` (code below) that doesn't load the correct view. It should load a page called `produits.jsp`.Instead of that, it loads the page `categories.jsp` of an other controller called `AdminCategorieController`. The two controllers belongs to the same package.
The pages `produits.jsp` and `categories.jsp` are in the same directory.

**AdminProduitsController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/adminProd")
public class AdminProduitsController {

    @Autowired
    private IAdminProduitsMetier metier;

    @RequestMapping(value="/index")
    public String home(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("produits",metier.listProduits());
        model.addAttribute("categories",metier.listCategories());
        model.addAttribute("produit", new Produit());
        return "produits";
    }
}
```

**AdminCategorieController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminCat")
public class AdminCategorieController implements HandlerExceptionResolver{

    @Autowired
    IAdminCategoriesMetier metier;

    @RequestMapping(value="/index")
    public String home(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("categorie",new Categorie());
        model.addAttribute("categories",metier.listCategories());
        return "categories";
    }
}
```

Here is the configuration file **servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <annotation-driven />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.aaronlbk.eboutique" />

    <beans:bean name="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"> 
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

The jsp files are strictly differents.

**categories.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f"%>

<head>
<!-- .getContextPath() contexte du projet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/style1.css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style1.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div id="formCat" class="cadre">

    <f:form modelAttribute="categorie" action="saveCat" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <table class="tab1">
            <tr>
                <td>ID categorie</td>
                <td><f:input path="idCategorie" />
                <td><f:errors path="idCategorie" cssclass="errors"></f:errors></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nom categorie</td>
                <td><f:input path="nomCategorie" />
                <td><f:errors path="nomCategorie" cssclass="errors"></f:errors></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </f:form>
</div>
</body>
```

**produits.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f"%>

<head>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style1.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div id="formProd" class="cadre">

    <f:form modelAttribute="produit" action="saveProd" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <table class="tab1">
            <tr>
                <td>ID Produit</td>
                <td><f:input path="idProduit" />
                <td><f:errors path="idProduit" cssclass="errors"></f:errors></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Catégorie</td>
                <td><f:select path="categorie.idCategorie" items="${categories}" itemValue="idCategorie" itemLabel="nomCategorie"/>
                <td><f:errors path="designation" cssclass="errors"></f:errors></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </f:form>
</div>

</body>
```

Why can cause the controller `AdminProduitsController` to return the page of an other controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the URL you are hitting to call the controller ?

May be you can try ModelAndView("viewname")

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index")
public ModelAndView home(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("produits",metier.listProduits());
    model.addAttribute("categories",metier.listCategories());
    model.addAttribute("produit", new Produit());
    return new ModelAndView("produits");
}
```

Comment: This looks correct. Few things you can try 

1. debugging and put breakput and check if its calling which controller. 

2. If you are using tomcat, please delete the work/Catalina/localhost directory and retry (stop tomcat, delete and start)

3. Try ModelAndView.

Comment: I have done the 3 points. I still have the issue. It is very strange

Comment: The issue is related to a raised exception during the execution that I didn't manage well. Thank you very well